# AngularJS 1.6 com carregamento de conteúdo assíncrono do plugin jQuery Steps

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, async

Estou com um problema que após carregar um conteúdo HTML dinamicamente de forma assíncrona com o plugin [jQuery Steps](http://www.jquery-steps.com/Examples#async):

```
<section data-mode="async" data-url="test.html"></section>
```

o `AngularJS` não detecta o conteúdo e com isso todos os elementos que contém as diretivas `ng-show` é exibido em vez de ser ocultado como esperado.

<del>Ambiente Punkler com o problema</del> - **Solucionado (Punkler atualizado)**:

http://plnkr.co/edit/6p1dVln2R9Pgb9ivoMcX?p=preview

PS: preciso que o carregamento seja assíncrono porque a quantidade de dados HTML que tenho que carregar é excessiva.

Comment: coloque todo o código dentro da tag section, exemplo: http://plnkr.co/edit/P09CFIoSp2G98LxJLZPn?p=preview

Comment: Não tem como fazer assim. Todo o código HTML pesaria demais o browser e a solução é fazer async justamente pra evitar carregamento de dados excessivo e a medida que o usuário fosse passando no Wizard o Plugin iria removendo a aba anterior. É um Questionário gigante que envia todas as respostas para um script. É preciso dividi-lo em partes o carregamento.

Comment: Do jeito que está no link da sua pergunta o código pouco importa se é carregado depois, ele sempre vai ser carregado na integra, estranho você dizer isso. Do jeito que está não dá mesmo, tem que fazer uma gambiarra do angular pegar esse elemento. Tem que ver se tem algo já feito para angular, eu pesquisei e não achei! se achar eu posto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solucionado (Punkler atualizado):**

Eu usei `ng-include` com `autoload`:
http://plnkr.co/edit/6p1dVln2R9Pgb9ivoMcX?p=preview

**O código:**

```
<!-- Jquery Steps HTML Template -->
<div id="wizard" ng-controller="wizardCtrl">
  <h3><i class="fa fa-question-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> Arroz</h3>
  <section>
    <div ng-if="index == '1'" ng-include="'test.html'" onload="finishLoading()"></div>
  </section>
</div>

<script>
  // Jquery Steps Plugin
  $wizard = $("#wizard");
  $wizard.steps({
    headerTag: "h3",
    bodyTag: "section",

    enableFinishButton: false,
    enablePagination: true,
    enableAllSteps: false,
    forceMoveForward: true,
    titleTemplate: "#title#",
    cssClass: "wizard tabcontrol",

    labels: {
      loading: ""
    }
  });

  angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('wizardCtrl', ['$scope', '$timeout', function($scope, $timeout){
        $scope.index = "1";

        $scope.finishLoading = function (){
            // jQuery Steps
            var index = $wizard.steps("getCurrentIndex");
            // ...

            return true;
        };
    }]);
</script>
```

Com `ng-if`, você pode carregar o conteúdo das abas on-demand, ou seja, você pode usar um método `jQuery Steps` chamado `getCurrentIndex` para obter o índice atual. <[Métodos](https://github.com/rstaib/jquery-steps/wiki/Methods)>

Usando `autoload` substitui o método `onContentLoaded` do carregamento assíncrono do jQuery Steps. <[Eventos](https://github.com/rstaib/jquery-steps/wiki/Settings)>